# One-to-One association with composite ID of owner Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I have a to make a one-to-one association between two Entities, but one of them must have two @Id. One is PRI another one is MUL. How must i declare composite id, and how do i need to map the classes?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSONS")
public class Person implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3451407520028311143L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS_ID")
    private Integer addressId;

    @Column(name ="NAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy= "person", cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    private Address address;
     ...
}
```

second class is mapped via @IdClass annotation

```
@Entity
@Table ( name = "ADDRESS" )
@IdClass(AddressKeys.class)
public class Address implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @Column ( name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Id
    @Column ( name = "PERSON_ID")
    private Integer idPerson;

    @Column ( name = "CITY" )
    private String city;

    @OneToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="PERSON_ID")
    private Person person;
...
}
```

and the id class

```
class AddressKeys implements Serializable{
    private Integer id;
    private Integer idPerson;

    //getters and setters

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        ...
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        ...
    }

}
```

So when i try to create and save a record i have a next error

> Could not open sessionRepeated column in mapping for entity:
>   hibernateMappedModels.base1.mappedClasses.oneToOne.Address column:
>   PERSON_ID (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   hibernateMappedModels.base1.Main.run(Main.java:45)    at
>   hibernateMappedModels.base1.Main.main(Main.java:24

I tryed to make an Id fields unInsertable and unUpdatable, and it was working, but i need them to be insertable and updatable; Is there any possibility to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I am confused by your mappings and not sure what is required other then the simple mappings below: if I am missing something then you will need to expand on your question. You are getting the error as you have mapped the column twice - once via the one-to-one and once as a simple property. Additionally, I am not sure why you require a composite key on address.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSONS")
public class Person implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3451407520028311143L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name ="NAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy= "person", cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    private Address address;

}

@Entity
@Table ( name = "ADDRESS" )
public class Address implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @Column ( name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column ( name = "CITY" )
    private String city;

    @OneToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="PERSON_ID")
    private Person person;
}
```